# Laravel5.8 jQuery post request saying its a get route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

In the html there a button so when you click it it goes toward an `.post` jQuery request goes to an controller that has to handle the request and then returning success json back, but I get an error (note the error is of the console.log(data)):

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/like 500 (Internal Server Error)

in the console. When I looked further the Laravel application returns this 
error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST, PUT, DELETE.

with this json response text:

```
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#197 …6}
  #routeResolver: null
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#45}
  +request: ParameterBag {#51}
  +query: ParameterBag {#51}
  +server: ServerBag {#47}
  +files: FileBag {#48}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#46}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#49}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: array:6 [▶]
  #pathInfo: "/comment/like"
  #requestUri: "/comment/like"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: null
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
```

So I understand that it has to be an POST route but the route in the web.php controller is this

```
Route::post('/comment/like','LikeController@likeIt')->name('likeIt');
```

And when I did some research on the 500 server error I got most answers where you need to add `csrfToken` but I have the `csrfToken` in the jQuery ajax request so I don't understand why its saying that its not an post request but a get request instead?

The controller

```
 public function likeIt()
 {
    $commentId = Input::get('commentId');
    $comment = Comment::find($commentId);

    $comment->likeIt();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'succes']);
 }
```

The html

```
 <button class="btn btn-sm" id="{{$comment->id}}" onclick="likeIt('{{$comment->id}}', this)"><i class="material-icons">done</i></button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function likeIt(commentId, elem) {
        const csrfToken='{{csrf_token()}}';
        $.post('{{route('likeIt')}}', {commentId: 
commentId,_token:csrfToken}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Add a DD, or Echo before $commentId = Input::get('commentId');